# How to encrypt vector tiles JSON response

Tags: geojson, tilestache, vector-tiles, encryption

I am using [TileStache](http://tilestache.org/) to serve vector tiles from `Postgres` and using [Tangram](https://github.com/tangrams/tangram) to display these tiles by passing url`http://localhost:8080/composite/{z}/{x}/{y}.json` in the data source. The response i get is in JSON format, which is what i wanted.

Now i just want to encrypt the `JSON` response so that it is not human readable at the client end and readable at server end but i don't know how to do it.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570831/can-i-encrypt-my-json-data) might be helpful for your problem as it was really helpful for me once when I was doing `JSON` encryption.

Comment: i am using url ('http://localhost:8080/composite/{z}/{x}/{y}.json') to get the response and also i cannot change my data format.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **transform** property on the **source** element to do your decryption.

documentation: 
https://mapzen.com/documentation/tangram/sources/#transform

Answer (score 0):

### You can't

Since the mapping library you're using is taking JSON as an input, and it is client-side, any data used by Tangram is necessarily human-readable client-side.